# How flatten laravel json api?

Tags: php, rest, laravel-5

I am developing a Restful json API using Laravel framework. I need to have flatten json response. When i serialize collection in eloquent relation the json will nested and make my lazy angularjs developer angry.

```
$employeehistory = Employeehistory::where('PersonId', '=', $id)->orderByRaw('CONVERT('.$orderby.' USING utf8) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci '. $orderFormat)
        ->with(['position', 'location.child.child'])
        ->paginate();
```

I get sth like this when serialize it to json:

```
"id": 4771,
      "PersonId": 5,
      "OrganizationId": 1000,
      "PositionId": 1,
      "position_name": "عضويت هيأت مديره مؤسسه مطالعات بين المللي كار- عضويت هيأت مديره مركز آموزش بين المللي تورين ايتاليا",
      "dutyfield": null,
      "SameLevel": null,
      "province_id": 17,
      "country_id": null,
      "employeePlaceNew": 36,
      "StartDate": "1900-01-01",
      "EndDate": null,
      "PhoneNo": null,
      "Address": null,
      "Comment": "عضويت هيأت مديره مؤسسه مطالعات بين المللي كار- عضويت هيأت مديره مركز آموزش بين المللي تورين ايتاليا",
      "active": 0,
      "created_at": "2016-11-08 16:15:37",
      "updated_at": "2016-11-08 16:15:37",
      "position": {
        "id": 1,
        "Name": "نامشخص"
      },
      "location": {
        "id": 36,
        "loc_name": "تهران(استان)",
        "loc_parent_fk": 29,
        "child": {
          "id": 29,
          "loc_name": "ايران",
          "loc_parent_fk": null,
          "child": null
        }
      }
    }
```

As you see it will nested on eager loading relationship and my UI developer doesn't like it. how I can flatten this json without make custom collections?

Comment: You need to create a new collection with whatever needed then return it as JSON. Nothing out of the box.